# Opening MOSFET's gate with low voltage PWM

Tags: pwm, low-power, high-voltage, low-voltage

I have PWM of very low frequency and very low duty cycle. And max voltage comes out are 3.3. But thats not enough to open the MOSFET's gate(IRFP250N). Now I want to amplify the voltage. I do not have op-amp right now. But I tried to use LM393P comparator but its seems too slow. So if I put LED direct to PWM output I can see it blinking but if I put it on output from comparator it stays on. So I assume comparator is not switching fast enough to make it blink.

Now, I'm thinking of using PNP transistor to switch on the MOSFET gate, but I'm not sure which one to buy ? or should I need to try something else ?

PS: I'm learning through internet and still very beginner. So I might have missed something.

Edit :

- PWM Frequency : 4Hz
- PWM DutyCycle : 2ms
- PWM Max Voltage : 3.3V

Edit 2 : For testing I used 12V instead of 200V.

And the test with LM393, the LED stays on, it doesn't blink. But if I turn off PWM, LED gets off too.

[image]

Comment: What is the largest voltage supply currently available in your system?  Is it 3.3V ?

Comment: 3.3V is PWM, however I need to control 80VDC through MOSFET.

Comment: How much current will pass through the transistor?

Comment: 5-10V I assume, I think 10V is enough to open MOSFET gate. So yea 10V through transistor.

Comment: Please re-read my question. I asked how much current will pass through the transistor, not how much voltage you will apply to the gate. Better yet, post a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Since you're still a "very beginner", you should learn that when you ask a question you should initially include as much information as possible about the problem in order to make life as easy as possible for whoever answers your question. For instance: in this case you should include the PWM frequency, duty cycle, and voltage, the load resistance and its supply voltage, and whether the transistor will be used on the high side or low side of the load, for starters. Better yet, as Dan Laks suggested, a schematic would be good and, in a perfect world, it should be properly annotated. :-)

Comment: Thank you @EMFields I will keep in mind next time. The reason I missed all that because I didn't know what more I needed to write :) however, I have no idea how much current it will take but it will be very low(around 20mA). All I know is about voltage. I will update the question though.

Comment: Your information should be in the question - not in the comments - or in both. And why do you say 80V max and then in other comments you say 200V. If you need it to be orange, fluffy, high temperature, edible, brave AND/OR 200V rated you should say so in the question.

Comment: What current? Tell us as much as possible. re you SWITCHING 200V or need a 200V part - and if you do not know you should tell us what you wish to achieve - NIT how you think it should be done as your possibly wrong idfeas will mislead you and us.

Comment: [40 mA at Vgs = 3V and > 200V rate](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TN0620%20B080813.pdf) | [Maybe 400 mA at Vgs=3V with good PCB copper](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TN0620%20B080813.pdf) - Better information leads to better answers

Comment: Yes, I did say 200V along with 80V. I updated the question. I hope its better to explain :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided so far, the schematic posted below will allow you to build something that works and that you can play around with using the active stuff you have on hand.

Since the LM393 is a dual comparator, you should spare out the unused one by connecting its  + and - inputs, and its output, to ground.

If you want to, you can also connect your LED in series with R5 to watch it blink, but make sure you don't connect it backwards or you'll destroy it.

Also, watch out for that 80 volts; it can give you a nasty little sting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The LM393 has an open collector output.
You MUST use a pullup resistor to use it to drive a load high.

There are many N Channel MOSFETs available which can be well driven at 3V. The IRFP250N is not one of them.

Low frequency PWM can be driven by a uC pin OK..
As frequency is increased a driver with more current drive capacity will be needed.

Comment: Yes I did use pullup resistor. Can you please tell me the names of N Channel MOSFETs that can hold upto 200VDC that can be open with 3VDC PWM. IRFP250N is just for testing till 80VDC.